# ASP.NET Core API Controller returns nothing even though it successfully completes the POST request

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the controller below where a player can upload pictures of their treasure.

It works!  However, when I test it using the Postman program, it doesn't return anything when I issue a `Return OK()`.

How can I get this controller to send some message to the user that the media was successfully uploaded? I thought returning an OK() would do that, but the response field in Postman is blank.

Is there way to do this?

Thanks!

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFormData([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile userFileUpload, [FromForm] Guid treasureId)
{
    int maxFileSize = 52428800; 
    var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".bmp", ".pdf", ".odt", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".rtf", ".txt" };

    if(userFileUpload.Length > maxFileSize)
    {
        return BadRequest("Maximum file size exceeded");
    }

    if(!allowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(userFileUpload.FileName)))
    {
        return BadRequest("This file is not a valid file type.");
    }

    if (treasureId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        return BadRequest("No treasureId was provided");
    }

    if (await _mediaFolderEngine.CopyFile(userFileUpload, treasureId))
    {
        return Ok();
    } 
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok() returns 200 Status Code, that means the request was successful, if you want to add a custom message with it also, you can do it like this

```
public IActionResult GetEmployees()  
{  
  return Ok("My Message");  
}
```